# Where can I find the original scientific articles on Heat index (published by either Larry P. Rothfusz or Steadman)?

Tags: climate-models

I'm curious to learn more about the research and thought that went into calculating the heat index. In particular I want to understand how Steadman or Rothfusz managed to fit a model (in terms of relative humidity and temperature) on data with variables related to human physiology.

Answer (score 4):

After having a look at the references of a few papers about heat index (like [this one](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9de1/82387865ce71fbe09a0af70c0c8f641b74d8.pdf)). It looks like the original publications you are looking for are

- **The Heat Index "Equation" (or, More Than You Ever Wanted to Know About Heat Index)** by Lans P. Rothfusz available [here](https://www.weather.gov/media/bgm/ta_htindx.PDF), and
- **The Assessment of Sultriness. Part I: A Temperature-Humidity Index Based on Human Physiology and Clothing Science**, by R. G. Steadman available [here](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/1520-0450%281979%29018%3C0861%3ATAOSPI%3E2.0.CO%3B2).

As a general suggestion, looking at the references in related papers is always a great way to find the original research articles on any topic.

Comment: Thanks Camilo! I'll make sure to use your advice in the future.